# Modifying Sharepoint 2013 search results based on culture

Tags: sharepoint-designer, search, custom-list, multilingual

Is it possible to display search results from a custom list based on the current culture (French and English only) of the user?

Using a simple list (Title, Description, URL, FrenchTitle, FrenchDescription), can we modify the search results to display the English Title/Description if we're an English user, and display the French columns if we are a French user?

Answer (score 0):

I would have two search results pages: one for English, one for French, maybe each with a nation flag at the top for both pages that links to the culture's search page (preserving the search). You can even have some javascript on the search results page that hits the user profile service (through REST) that will try to determine which search result page to navigate to upon searching on a user profile property.